# highcharts range selector buttons spacing issue

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to resize the range selector. i'm able to change button sizes but they are coming close to each other. how can i increase the font size without increasing the space between buttons. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control the `rangeSelector` buttons by `buttonSpacing` and `buttonTheme` options. Setting a fixed `width` should be enough in your case:

```
rangeSelector: {
    buttonSpacing: 5,
    buttonTheme: {
        width: 30,
        style: {
            fontSize: 16
        }
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5f6aro7t/

API Reference: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/rangeSelector.buttonSpacing

Comment: Thanks ppotaczek. it worked for me. can you also help me in putting the space between buttons and zoom label?

Comment: Hi sai, Yes, of course. You need to use `buttonPosition` and add a small wrap: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/tskb3cf1/

Comment: awesome ppotaczek. i did worked but i have three different resolutions. how can i set this.zoomText.attr value to those corresponding resolutions

Comment: Hi sai, You can make the `x` value dependent on the width of the chart: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ubnLr8m4/

Comment: that works. Thank you so much. do you know how to style donut chart second level series names.

Comment: Hi sai, Do you mean the `dataLabels`? Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3h7gbu0f/

Comment: yes datalabels. which all are in the red in example jsfiddle you sent me. i'm able to style them but i have three different resolutions ipad pro(width 2048) ipad (width 1024) and mobile (width 480). but chart not showing according the resolution. for example if i open in ipad pro its showing ipads styling. in ipad its showing mobile styling. some thing wrong with responsive rules. but i'm using same rules for others charts those working fine. do you know what i'm missing?

Comment: @sai, Please provide me with some live example, I can not help you without checking your code.

Comment: responsive: {rules: [{condition: {maxWidth:2048}, chartOptions: { series: [{dataLabels: { style: {fontSize: '25px',
                                color: 'red'
                                        },}}]}},
                      {condition: {
                       maxWidth: 1024},
                    chartOptions: {
                        series: [{
                            dataLabels: {
                                style: {
                                    fontSize: '35px',
                                    color: 'green'
                                },}}]}}] }

Comment: sorry. i don't know how to make jsfiddle so sent code. thats my responsive rules code

Comment: @sai, it is very easy to create a jsfiddle example, so please try. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/hzct52yj/ it looks like that you need to use more conditions.

Comment: may be because data not there. but the code is same for responsive

Comment: @sai, I think that you should add both `maxWidth` and `minWidth` conditions. If this does not help, please create another stackoverflow question, because it is a completely different question.

Comment: Hi ppotaczek. 0


i'm trying to show dates in x-axis. but it showing like this enter image description here. my series date data is {04/23/2017, 04/30/2017,05/07/2017,05/14/2017,05/21/2017,06/04/2017. my x-axis configuration isxAxis: {
                tickAmount: 5,
                type: 'datetime',
                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                    day: '%m/%d/%Y',
                    week: '%m/%d/%Y',
                    month: '%m/%d/%Y',
                 },}, can you help me

Comment: this is the question i have created. highcharts x-axis irregular date intervels issue

Comment: Hi ppotaczek. I'm trying to show dates on x-axis. but they are showing one day off. can you help me. this is the question i have created. highcharts x-axis date issue

Comment: Hi sai, Please provide me with a link to the topic.

Comment: Hi ppotaczek. sure. this is the new question i have created highcharts x-axis date issue.